# Can Groovy copy a class signature but modify implementations

Tags: java, groovy, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to copy the interface of a groovy script exactly but forward all the methods to a method like invokeMethod or methodMissing.

This is related to [My other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205496/how-can-i-intercept-a-call-from-java-to-groovy-or-simulate-this-easily) (But I gave up on the "easily" part) which explains why I can't actually use invokeMethod or the ProxyMetaClass--in short, because my method is being called from java and none of groovy's grooviness works for that invocation.

So I'm stuck trying to duplicate the class signature and forward calls to the original class.

This probably involves AST transforms, but I'm still trying to wrap my brain around those, any examples of using the AST to do something like this (or any other ideas at all) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get all the *grooviness* to work by having your well defined use case execute within the context of a [GroovyShell](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html)

Comment: The problem is that a canned java app is scanning my groovy class for annotations and then calling back into it directly.  I'm not sure how I can get it to call through GroovyShell--or what you are suggesting...  Any chance you could give a code example?